# javascript, problems trying to apply .includes() over a property expressed inside an array (TypeError: .includes is not a function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following group of elements that describe the title of an activity, and the years it was carried out in array format.

```
activities: [
 { title: "Playing soccer at school",
   years: [2023,2024] 
  },
 { title: "Playing guitar at home",
   years: [2022,2023,2024]
  },
 { title: "Listening music",
   years: [2022,2023,2024]
 }
]
```

When I try to filter the activities that were carried out in the year 2022, I cannot achieve it in any way. I copy the function I used using .filter and .includes

```
const activities2022 = activities.filter((element) => {
                 const periodArray = element.years
                 return periodArray.includes(2022)
               });
```

In the browser console I always see the result "TypeError: periodArray.includes is not a function" . I obviously have two problems that I don't know how to handle: searching within an array, using numbers not strings.

The function does work, for example if I execute it on the "element.title". If I put "Playing" inside the .includes, it returns the first two activities (looks for a string within a string)

What would be the correct way to use this function by searching numbers within an array? I have tried using element.years.toString to transform the array into a string, also changing periodArray.includes(2022) to periodArray.includes("2022").

Obviously I am doing something wrong in the array transformation. Is there any other way to address this problem?

Nothing worked, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible for me to tell if this is a typo or your actual problem so I'll post this as an answer.

Your `filter` code is totally fine. Your declaration of activities has syntax errors:

```js
activities = [
   { 
     title: "Playing soccer at school",
     years: [2023,2024] 
   },
   { 
     title: "Playing guitar at home",
     years: [2022,2023,2024],
   }, // <- MISSING BRACE AND COMMA
   { 
     title: "Listening music",
     years: [2022,2023,2024]
   }, // <- MISSING BRACE AND COMMA
]

console.log(activities.filter((element) => {
 const periodArray = element.years
 return periodArray.includes(2022)
}))
```

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake when transcribing the elements to the forum (I just corrected them for viewing). I have tried this small code that I put in as an example and it works perfectly in the online console. I am doubting that it is some specific problem within react, I don't understand why has this problem with .includes